# Broken images after download using php curl

Tags: php, curl

I have a class that allows me to download images using php curl. My class looks like this:

```
function getImage($img, $path) {
    $fullpath = basename($img);

    $ch = curl_init($img);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
    $rawData = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    if(file_exists($fullpath)) {
        unlink($fullpath);
    }

    $fp = fopen($path.$fullpath, "w+");
    fwrite($fp, $rawData);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

This works okay for most images but there are also instances in which I get broken images instead. I've tried checking the path of the image from the website and it's correct. My question is, why is this happening and how can I prevent images being downloaded broken?

Comment: Have you compared the contents of the file with the original image file?

Comment: Not sure what you meant by compare but they have the same file name. Only difference is the file location and the original image file is not broken but the one I downloaded is broken.

Comment: Where are you downloading the images from -- is it from various different sites? Are the broken images only from certain sites? I.e. could the site in question be breaking the images as a hotlinking prevention. Can you do a binary compare of the good image and the broken one? I'd also open a broken image in a text editor and see if it's actually just a HTTP error message.

Comment: Does this have to do with the size of the images being downloaded?

Comment: @SpaceDog, thanks a lot for the suggestion. I've tried comparing the url of the image from the website and the url of the image that I got. There was a space in my url.